# How to omit semicolon that ends each row in csv file when importing (read.csv) into R?

Tags: r, csv

I want to import a csv file into R with the read.csv function.
There is always a error that occurs, and I believe it is due to the fact that each row of the data in the csv file also ends with a semicolon, whereas the header row doesn't have that semicolon.

```
header1;header2;header3     # here, there's no semicolon at the end of the line
cell1;cell2;cell3;          # here, there are semicolons! 
cell4;cell5;cell6;          # I think those are causing the issue
```

The error is: "duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed"

I am working with a large set of csv-files, so I am hoping there is a way I can somehow ignore the last semicolon in the data rows since I would like to use the first row as names.

The code that I used is:

```
df <- read.csv("test.csv", sep = ";", dec = ".", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Use header=FALSE and use the skip argument to skip the header.  note that when posting to SO you should provide all input and code so that readers can reproduce the problem on their own machine.  If it's long then you need to cut it down so that your example is minimal but still illustrates the problem.

Comment: Why does the third line use commas as separators?

Comment: Assuming the data is actually comma separated and not semicolon separated, or mixed delimited as your post seems to indicate, I would use `comment.char = ";"`

Comment: Else, if it is mixed, I'd gsub the document before reading it in so that all semicolons are commas (or vice versa) and then read it in and delete the last column that should have all missing data.

Comment: @James I mistyped the comas - all rows are  semicolon delimited.

Comment: If i use 'comment.char = ";"', the result is, that only the first column is loaded. Probably because the argument means that everything after the first semicolon is a comment, doesn't it?

Comment: Is it too complex to add a fake column name in header ? using sed or any command line text editor to add a ';fakeheader' to the first line sounds the best way to fix you input file before loading it. Example: `sed -i '1 s/$/;fakeheader/'`should do. remove the -i if you just wish to test and not update in place.

Comment: @Tensibai Changing the files is not an option since other tools are accessing them in the way they are constructed now.. So basically, I really need to modify the loading process if that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what's happening, as described in the help file `?read.csv`:

> If there is a header and the first row contains one fewer field than
>   the number of columns, the first column in the input is used for the
>   row names.

```
a <- "header1;header2;header3
cell1;cell2;cell3;
cell4;cell5;cell6;"
read.table(text=a, sep=";")  
##       header1 header2 header3
## cell1   cell2   cell3      NA
## cell4   cell5   cell6      NA
```

So your data must have duplicate values in the first column, because it's treating those as row names.

I don't see a way to tell `read.csv` or `read.table` not to do this, so you'll need to read the column names and the data separately.

```
out <- read.table(text=a, sep=";", header=FALSE, skip=1)
out <- out[,-ncol(out)]
names(out) <- read.table(text=a, sep=";", nrow=1, header=FALSE,
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
out
##   header1 header2 header3
## 1   cell1   cell2   cell3
## 2   cell4   cell5   cell6
```

Or in one line (without the extra column removed):

```
read.table(text=a, sep=";", header=FALSE, skip=1,
           col.names=c(read.table(text=a, sep=";", nrow=1, header=FALSE, 
           stringsAsFactors=FALSE),"X"))
##   header1 header2 header3  X
## 1   cell1   cell2   cell3 NA
## 2   cell4   cell5   cell6 NA
```